# Does it make sense to ship python source files as part of the egg file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just created an EGG file on a python project and it created a zip file which contained the source as well as the python compiled file(s). Does it make sense to ship the source as part of the EGG file, if so how can I avoid it during egg file creation?

Comment: Compiled files? What do you mean?

Comment: .pyc files (python compiled files)

Comment: Why do you want to package `pyc` files in an egg? An egg normaly contains the `py` files.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but one of the open source projects was bundling both the .py as well as the .pyc files. I was under the impression that only pyc files need to be part of the egg package.

Comment: If the project is open source the recommended shipping method is .py files only. .pycs can be generated by Python interpreter when the egg is run for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

(a) It makes sense

(b) If you really want to avoid it, then just delete the .py files from the egg.

(c) I bet one can reconstruct the full source (less comments) from .pyc files.

Comment: What tool can be used to achieve (c)